# Dual booting elementary OS, does not boot properly after install

Tags: dual-boot, elementary-os, macintosh

I'm trying to dual boot OS X and elementary OS on a Mac. I've followed e.g. [these](http://www.elementarynow.com/dual-booting-elementary-os-and-osx/) instructions. The first question is this: I have not once got the "install alongside" option
so I've manually created root and swap partitions. Is there a reason for this? I believe I should get "install alongside Mac OS X"?

Anyway, the install goes through just fine with manual partitioning, but when I reboot after the install, I get the (initramfs) prompt. If I just reboot again after the (initframs) prompt I only get a black screen or the underscore blinking in the top left corner. I ran boot-repair which only resulted in grub rescue after reboot. I also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox) (the 1st answer). So the second question is how to fix this?

I'm using rEFInd. Another question is, in case I can't get it to boot properly, how do I remove the extra boot options from rEFInd that stay there also after deleting the linux partitions.

Answer (score 1):

When you partition your hard drive to prepare for the install, just shrink the Macintosh HD partition and leave several gigabytes of free space (you may need to create a partition and change the format to "free space").  Elementary OS will format and utilize this free space while itself allowing you to install it alongside OS X.

Comment: Wish it was that easy. Did you read what I wrote? 1) of course I shrinked the OS X partition 2) I did not get the install alongside option so I created the partitions by hand 3) nothing seemed to go wrong in the installation 4) the above initframs thing happened anyway. Anyway, that was with eOS Luna, I had better luck with Freya, don't know why but it works.